# What is the difference between ColladaLoader.js and ColladaLoader2.js given by Mr.Doob in examples folder of github?

Tags: github, three.js, collada

What is the difference between `ColladaLoader.js` and `ColladaLoader2.js` given by Mr.Doob in `examples/` folder of GitHub?

Does one have an advantage over the other?

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you are referring to [`mrdoob`](https://github.com/mrdoob) [`three.js`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js) JavaScript 3D library.

Its [`examples/js/loaders`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/examples/js/loaders) folder do include a [`ColladaLoader.js`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/loaders/ColladaLoader.js) and a [`ColladaLoader2.js`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/loaders/ColladaLoader2.js) file.

Note that there was an issue with the first one (see [issue 7388](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/7388#issuecomment-149743650)): use the one from the dev branch: [`dev/examples/js/loaders/ColladaLoader.js`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/dev/examples/js/loaders/ColladaLoader.js)

As mentioned in [issue 7256](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/7256#issuecomment-144566948):

> the current `ColladaLoader` is out of control.
>   I've started a new `ColladaLoader2` from scratch in the `dev` branch.

So the 2 is a re-implementation of the first one.

Comment: So that means the second is actually the one to go with? Why didn't they fix the first one instead? @VonC

Comment: @LinusGeffarth Yes, and it is still actively maintained: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/commit/291ab8808a2f79f894c3330998dd4ef2188da5ac